# What is this HTTP_REFERRER "WordPress/4.1.2"

Tags: headers, api, http

On our website we have huge traffic with same IP and referrer **"WordPress/4.1.2; http://www.xxxx.com"**. The log line looks like:

> 62.24.2.2 - - [22/Apr/2015:17:28:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/04/randevouz.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 791898 "-"
>   "WordPress/4.1.2; http://www.xxxx.com"

The IP and domain xxxx.com are real and I can see the website who doing it, but before block I want to know what this is.

Comment: It seems that someone is loading an image from your website. There was a time when people was blocking such things at server level because it consumes your bandwidth to show the image in another website. Personally, I don't care about such thing and I think most of webmasters doens't care neither

Comment: I know. But I think he is using some standard software, so I am trying to block more "broad".

Comment: If you know, what is the question. You asked "I want to know what this is.". The `WordPress/4.1.2` referrer indicates that it is using [WP HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API), I think.

Comment: I see. This is the answer then. Thanks. If you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log entry indicates the someone form that IP is requesting a image file from your site. The referrer "WordPress/4.1.2" indicates that it is probably using [WP HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API), so the image is not just inserted in HTML (using `<img>` or any other HTML element) but requested server-side. Why? It can not be known with the provided information; maybe the other site is downloading the image to its own server.